# Can not add reference to .NET Core class library in ASP.NET Core project

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I've created a new `ASP.NET Core` project and a class library for it in VS 2015 (Update 3).

This is how `project.json` looks like:

```
    {
      "version": "1.0.0-*",

      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
      },

      "frameworks": {
        "netstandard1.6": {
          "imports": "dnxcore50"
        }
      }
    }
```

And this is a `project.json` of the ASP.NET Project:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Now I can't add my class library to my site as 'dependency can't be resolved'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see a reference to your library in your application's `dependencies` section. If your library and your application are in the same solution, make sure you use `target: project` like so:

**project.json** of ASP.NET Core project:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "MyLibrary": {
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "target": "project"
    }
}
```

Otherwise, NuGet will look for your library as a package instead of looking in the solution.

Comment: Thank you @Nate Barbettini, it has been helpful. Now my ASP.NET Core projects builds fine but I'm still having an issue with Resharper. It still doesn't see libraries. By any chance do you know a cure for this?

Comment: @alexxjk That's a known issue with Resharper unfortunately. You'll either have to wait for the next release, or get the beta (EAP) version.