# Cannot Call My Class and method in .Net Core Class Library From Asp.Net Core app

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I have googling before, in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tutorials/using-on-windows) and in [stackoverflow for example this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38636225/can-not-add-reference-to-net-core-class-library-in-asp-net-core-project).
for dependencies is solve, not getting error. but when I want to call my method in class (on .Net Class Library) not showing in Intellisense.I can't call namespace reference.

I was check and compare my `project.json` with result my  googling and was downgrade `netstandard library to 1.4 and 1.3`, still can't call my method...Uninstall my resharper not help to, still getting error.

I am using Vs.2015 update 3.

.Netcore v.1.0.1

here is my `project.json` in .Net Core Class Library ,name Project "DataContextCore"

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-1",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.4": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

and here is my project.json in Asp.Net Core

```
  "dependencies": {
   ....other package library
    "DataContextCore": {"target" : "project", "version" : "1.0.0-1"}
  },
```

does anyone know why it happened. or or indeed asp.net core is still not stable until now.
I am very frustrated with asp.net cores and with all its configurations, look like fools or asp.net core is not stable..I hope microsoft guys can answer this.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: i not have error....just cannot call all function in other .NET Core Class Library.....when restore dependencyis solve, not getting error...just that.

Comment: Now I try Uninstall or Repair My Visual Studio, may getting update when install again....thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I would remove that rc2 reference that is outdated, update it like this:

```
"NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0-*"

"netstandard1.6": {
        "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
```

Comment: sorry, Update...I was update to remove like you sugested, but still not work.

Comment: Now I try Uninstall or Repair My Visual Studio, may getting update when install again....thanks for your time